# There's a mistake But I don't know how to solve it

Tags: python-3.x

IndentationError: expected an indented block.....

```
import time
def countdown(n) :
while n > 0: #here Error
print (n)
n = n - 1
if n ==0:
print('BLAST OFF!')
countdown(50)
```

Comment: You must indent the body of a function, as well as the body of a `while` block. Please read a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best practice for programming is to learn how to google. Whenever you get an error, search for that on internet.
The below code snippet will work for you.

```
import time
def countdown(n) :
    while n > 0: #here Error
       print (n)
       n = n - 1
       if n ==0:
           print('BLAST OFF!')
countdown(50)
```

Python don't have curly braces. So to mark everything you need to ident. Try above code it should work.

Comment: Sorry i forgot it should be like:
if n==0:
    print("BLAST OFF!')
countdown(50)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look into the python docs:

In Python the indentation is not just cosmetics, but part of the syntax to define blocks and block scope. In your case, you obviously want to define a function named countdown. And this function is a block which must be indented. And that's what your error message states.

Your code should look like:

```
import time

def countdown(n) :
    while n > 0: #here you need to indent 
        print (n)
        n = n - 1
        if n ==0: #this may or may not be within the while loop as it's entirely redundant
            print('BLAST OFF!') #and the statements here is also a block

countdown(50)
```

Just have a look into the docs. E. g. here https://www.python-course.eu/python3_blocks.php

Good luck!

Comment: Body of `while` should also be indented.

Comment: @juzraai: Good catch